# How to record voice and guitar with Zoom H6

Tags: recording, voice, guitar, zoom-h6

I have a Zoom H6 that I use mainly for voice recording purposes.

Now I want to make a video for a friend who is singer. Will be voice + guitar.

I'm wondering how should I setup the H6 with one of the included microphones in order to record these.

Should I use 2 microphones at the same time connected to the H6 (one for voice and other for guitar) or can I get a decent result with just one mic? (Remember I just have 3 included microphones (X/Y, MS and Shotgun)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will almost always want to use two microphones. Yes, you could do it with one, but it will require you getting it perfectly placed, and it will not give you optimal sound quality for either guitar or voice.

So set up a vocal mic and one for your guitar.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please recommend me a good mic for vocals that I can use with my Zoom?